# How to remove Apache error, showing this in Apache error log

Tags: apache

Apache error logs:

```
[Sun Dec 06 12:09:48.500485 2015] [ssl:warn] [pid 4468:tid 384] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Sun Dec 06 12:09:49.020821 2015] [ssl:warn] [pid 4468:tid 384] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Sun Dec 06 12:09:55.209334 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4468:tid 384] AH00455: Apache/2.4.17 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2d PHP/5.6.14 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sun Dec 06 12:09:55.209334 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4468:tid 384] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC11 Server built: Oct 13 2015 10:54:13
[Sun Dec 06 12:09:55.209334 2015] [core:notice] [pid 4468:tid 384] AH00094: Command line: 'C:\\xampp\\apache\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/xampp/apache'
[Sun Dec 06 12:09:55.283393 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4468:tid 384] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 2364
[Sun Dec 06 12:09:56.648382 2015] [ssl:warn] [pid 2364:tid 376] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Sun Dec 06 12:09:56.952603 2015] [ssl:warn] [pid 2364:tid 376] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Sun Dec 06 12:09:57.241836 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 2364:tid 376] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.
```

Answer (score 1):

Thoose logs are Warn & Notice level, here is the list of error levels, and the comand to remove all messages lower than warn :

```
# Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit, alert, emerg.
LogLevel error
```

If you want to resolve you warn level, you need to buy a SSL certificate instead of self sign it